# Mysql stored procedure using in trigger

Tags: mysql

I want to use procedure in trigger. I try that:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER insert_hastaodeme
AFTER INSERT ON hasta_odeme FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF (NEW.odeme_tur='Nakit') THEN  
EXEC procedure_kasa_cariodeme NEW.odeme_islemtarih, NEW.odeme_odemetarih, NEW.unvan, NEW.odeme_tutar, NEW.odeme_birim, NEW.odeme_tur, NEW.odeme_no, NEW.odeme_aciklama, NEW.odeme_id, 1;
END IF;

END; 
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But It is return syntax error like that:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'procedure_kasa_cariodeme NEW.odeme_islemtarih, 
>   NEW.odeme_odemetarih, NEW.unvan, ' at line 6

How can I fix it?

Comment: `EXEC` is not valid in MySQL, perhaps you mean [`CALL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/call.html)?

Comment: When in doubt about the syntax, consult [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/).

Comment: @tadman that's a bit radical! What do you think SO is for?! :-)

Comment: @Nick To educate people about the availability of the fantastic documentation!